# How to update Android on Samsung Tab 8.9 - GT-P7300

Tags: updates, device-firmware

I have a tablet Samsung Tab 8.9
Model number: GT-P7300
It has Android 3.2 and it should be upgradable to Android 4.0.4

I downloaded a big zip file named "XSG-P7300JPLP7-20121217--www.SamSony.net--.zip" - 419 MB
It contains various .md5 files and a file named
"P7300JPLP7_P7300OJPLP4_P7300XXLQ6_HOME.tar"

I also downloaded latest Odin - v3.14

But I have no idea how to tell Odin to make use of those files.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do the terms "BL", "AP", "CP", and "CSC" mean in Odin?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/176515/what-do-the-terms-bl-ap-cp-and-csc-mean-in-odin)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where are the download images for Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/229647/where-are-the-download-images-for-android)

Comment: https://www.xda-developers.com/update-firmware-any-samsung-phone

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/141474/131553

Comment: Thanks, so I should use AP. What version of Odin though? I posted the question on XDA forum too - https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/what-version-of-odin-i-need-for-samsung-tab-8-9-gt-p7300.4205497/

Comment: I was reading somewhere that the Odin version should correspond to the year in which the update you plan to flash is released// No idea how to go about finding that